# Count on the table MS access with c#

Tags: ms-access

I have students records. If I get John repeats more than 2 times on my database, how can I count how many records John has on the database?

```
________________
Name |    Grade
________________

John |    F
Mo   |    A
John |    F
```

I want to know how many F's John gets? I'm connecting this database with C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT count(Grade),Name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: How can I use the new table after making this query on my code? When I run the code the new data adds on new rows, it doesn't add to the old data if the student has a new grade. For example, John gets another F, when I run my code and give John F, it doesn't add to John's record.

Comment: @Kamal I am not clear. Can you please explain little bit more

Comment: Now, when I want to add another record to John, it should give me "3" on the count field because it is 2 now, but when I add another record it gives me another row for the new record.

Comment: No man. Definitely it will give count value as 3 if the name is `John`

Comment: I did a query to the table and put you SQL code on it. After that, I made a table for that query to be a new table. When I used that new table on my code to store data in, the new data of John adds new row

Answer (score 0):

You will have to group on both *Name* and *Grade*:

```
SELECT 
    [Name],
    Grade,
    Count(*) As Achieved
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    [Name],
    Grade
```